# Multiple dynamic mod_rewrite in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a bunch of pages that are all currently like this: site.com/browse.php?cat=XXX and a bunch of pages that are index.php?p=QQQ

How can I make this site.com/XXX and site.com/QQQ in 2 rules? How can I make rewrite rules that recognises that if some pages should be redirected to browse and some to index?

I have tried to this with multiple rules but then it always only takes the first rule (e.g. trying to redirect to browse.php?cat=QQQ).

Thanks

Comment: are the XXX and QQQ values distinguishable in some way - for example, does one always contain alphabetic values and the other not.  If they overlap in anyway, then I think you're out of luck.

Comment: so basically if i would change it to this:

site.com/QQQ (i would not like to change it to site.com/index/QQQ)
site.com/browse/XXX

it would be possible? because Ive tried this and then going to site.com/browse/XXX will try to redirect it to site.com/index.php?p=browse/XXX rather than browse.php?cat=XXX

Comment: I would go this way: redirect site.com/QQQ to site.com/index.php?p=QQQ and site.com/browse/XXX to site.com/browse.php?cat=XXX and make an appropriate rules for these rewrites... While site.com/browse/XXX must be the first rule and site.com/QQQ the second one. With [L] switch.

Answer (score 1):

You need some way of distinguishing between index.php and browse.php. Here is a suggestion:

```
 site.com/QQQ
 site.com/browse/XXX
```

The redirect rules that match and process the above URLs are:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following two lines prevent further rewriting on second pass
RewriteRule ^browse\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# The following two lines cause mod_rewrite to do another pass
RewriteRule ^browse/(.+) browse.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: would it be possible to have:
site.com/QQQ and
site.com/browse/XXX ?

what would the mod_rewrite code be because I've tried this and couldnt get it to work!

Comment: if i want to add more rules, e.g. for profile.php, would I just script it in the similar way to the browse rule and put it underneath before the index rule?

Comment: Yes I believe it will work. Keep in mind that (i) you need to clone browse rule in both sections (ii) the index rule must be last in both sections.

Comment: sorry to be so demanding, but could you include an example of multiple rewrite rules? also one with multiple variables (e.g. browse/QQQ/PPP/WWW). thanks (there is no way to private message here...) ver much appreciated!